# Putting the checkbox value into a session variable and then redirecting

Tags: php, html

An interesting (to me) problem here. I have some data returned back from a web service. What I'm trying to do is create a page which, when the check box is ticked, automatically redirects to a new page and displays that specific data.

The code currently looks like this

```
<table width="90%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="col-md-4 text-center" width="25%">Title</th>
                <th class="col-md-2 text-center" width="25%">Venue</th>
                <th class="col-md-4 text-center" width="20%">Date</th>
                <th class="col-md-1 text-center" width="20%">Length</th>
                <th class="col-md-1 text-center" width="10%">View</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php
                $url = getUrlForMethod("Appointments", $_SESSION["Username"]);
                $response = callGetAPI($url);
                $decoded = json_decode($response);
                foreach($decoded->AppointmentList as $d)
                {
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td width="25%"><?php echo $d->AppointmentList->MeetingName; ?></td>
                    <td width="25%"><?php echo $d->AppointmentList->Venue; ?></td>
                    <td width="20%"><?php echo $d->AppointmentList->DateTimeFrom; ?></td>
                    <td width="20%"><?php echo $d->AppointmentList->Length; ?></td>
                    <td width="10%"><input type="checkbox" name="view" value="<?php echo $d->AppointmentList->MeetingId; ?>" onclick="<?php $_SESSION["meetingId"]=$d->AppointmentList->MeetingId;?>; Javascript:window.location.href='showmeeting.php'"></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
                }
                ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I can't use a form here though (part of the specs).

The issue is that irrespective of which checkbox is checked, it is only the final one from the list that ever shows. Is it possible to set the session variable to be the value for the checked box and then redirect but without a form?

Comment: This is probably an html-issue here... does each checkbox have a unique id? if not - then your browser will just provide the last one's value. You might need to alter your code so each checkbox has a unique id (not just a unique value)

Comment: You have a problem in your logic! you just can not use `onclick="<?php $_SESSION["meetingId"]=$d->AppointmentList->MeetingId;?>;` and expect to set the session on the server-side when you click on the checkbox on the client-side! I'm not sure that you want to do or if using `session` for what you want to do is the best practice or not. but if you really want to use you can use `ajax` in the `onclick` event and send the `ID` to a `server-side script` and set the session in that script, then then the ajax result returns, redirect the page.

Comment: @TarynEast - all the id's are unique.@EhsanT - I would have thought that this code would have injected the value when the checkbox is created

Answer (score 0):

Not pretty sure it's really what you want, but if I follow exactly the description in the 1st paragraph of your question, you might merely make the `MeetingId` to be added as a query param to the url you're redirecting to.

Then it's up to your `something.php` script to use this param (from `$_GET['meetingid']`, and not from some `$_SESSION` data) to build the desired page, which is replacing the current one as you asked.

So it might look like this:

```
<table width="90%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="col-md-4 text-center" width="25%">Title</th>
            <th class="col-md-2 text-center" width="25%">Venue</th>
            <th class="col-md-4 text-center" width="20%">Date</th>
            <th class="col-md-1 text-center" width="20%">Length</th>
            <th class="col-md-1 text-center" width="10%">View</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<?php
$url = getUrlForMethod("Appointments", $_SESSION["Username"]);
$response = callGetAPI($url);
$decoded = json_decode($response);
foreach($decoded->AppointmentList as $d) {
?>
        <tr>
            <td width="25%"><?php echo $d->AppointmentList->MeetingName; ?></td>
            <td width="25%"><?php echo $d->AppointmentList->Venue; ?></td>
            <td width="20%"><?php echo $d->AppointmentList->DateTimeFrom; ?></td>
            <td width="20%"><?php echo $d->AppointmentList->Length; ?></td>
            <td width="10%">
                <input type="checkbox" onclick=
                  "javascript: window.location.href = 'showmeeting.php?meetingid=' +
                  '<?php echo $d->AppointmentList->MeetingId; ?>'">
            </td>
        </tr>
<?php
}
?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

You'll notice that I dropped both `name` and `value` attributes of the `<input>` since they're useless here.

BTW I'm a bit surprised by all the `$d->AppointmentList->...`: written so, it means that your `$decoded` response has an `AppointmentList` property containing a list of objects which themselves have an `AppointmentList` property... Are you sure of that?